# Why am I getting 0 in an index out-bounds after allocating memory with calloc() instant of an error?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I would like to ask you about some doubt I have about memory allocation with calloc;

I am trying to create a bool 2d matrix which would be represented by 0 for false and 1 for true.
I have the following code:

```
// Create a 2D array
int **createArrayBool(int row, int col){
    // Allocate memory for 2D array
    int **arr = (int**) calloc(row,sizeof(int*));
    for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ ){
        arr[i] = (int*) calloc(col,sizeof(int));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

In main() I called the function:

`int **arr2d = createArrayBool(2,2);`

My doubt is that when I print the value let’s say at position arr2d[1][5] I got 0 but I only allocated col < 2 and I did not get an error.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior

Comment: C doesn't promise to issue an error in such a case of [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).  It doesn't promise anything at all, which means anything can happen, from no apparent effect to your worst nightmare.  You simply have to design your code to not do that.

Comment: To repeat an analogy I've used before, your question is like asking "I drove through a red traffic light and nothing happened.  I was expecting the police to stop me from doing so.  Why didn't they?"  You got away with it... this time.  Next time someone may crash into you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)